# How to display JSON data as matrix (like matrix in SSRS)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**How to display JSON data as matrix (like matrix in SSRS)?**

My json:

```
var data = [{"ID":1,"SUB":"English","SCORE":10},{"ID":1,"SUB":"Spanish","SCORE":20},{"ID":1,"SUB":"France","SCORE":30},{"ID":2,"SUB":"English","SCORE":20},{"ID":2,"SUB":"Spanish","SCORE":30},{"ID":2,"SUB":"France","SCORE":50}];
```

I want to display this JSON to HTML:

[image]

How to do?

Comment: Cool, where is the html that and Javascript you tried to do this with in your question above? Please show what you tried

Comment: Cool, I know here is not writing code service, but I am here for kind. I can't try any code in this. failed failed.